# How to bind the values returned from a http service call to a field dropdown in the UI in Angular6

Tags: http, angular6, angular-httpclient, angular-material-6

I get a response like posted below once I call a post service, The data of the bankName that I get from here I would want to use as select values for field drop down in my UI
How could I bind these values to an object so I could do an interpolation at the UI for the same.
Thanks in advance.

```
"data":[{"bankCode":"1","bankName":"A AND N STATE CO OPERATIVE BANK LTD"},{"bankCode":"2","bankName":"A B E CO OPERATIVE BANK LTD"},{"bankCode":"3","bankName":"A C C BANK"}...
```

I have tried it this way, but get the following error

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

This is my Service Code -:

```
getIncCompany(): Observable<PolicyData> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  let body = '{}';
  return this.http
  .post<PolicyData>(this.apiUrl, body, { headers: headers })
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('getIncCompany: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

This is the component code

```
getIncCompany() {
    this.policyService.getIncCompany()
    .subscribe(data => { 
     this.policyinc = data,
    (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    console.log(this.policyinc);
    }
            // this.vehicleDetailsForm.reset(),
);
    }
```

And this is the html template code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 m-form__group-sub">
                                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                                                <mat-label> Handicapped Discount
                                                </mat-label>
                                                <mat-select placeholder="Select">
                                                    <mat-option value="option" *ngFor="let polB of policyinc">{{ polB.bankName }}</mat-option>
                                                </mat-select>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: well my wild guess is that ```getIncCompany(): Observable<PolicyData>``` observable should be ```Observable<PolicyData[]>```  since you are getting an array, not a single object? In any case you should debug the javascript and check if the ```policyinc``` is really an array

Comment: @Ernis, thanks, did try with the way you have told as well, but doesn't help as yet, and yes it does return an array, unable to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: also, can you check if the error happens after the data is loaded or before, because it might be because your initial (before loading) data is incorrect and throws the error, try initializing it with an empty array: ```public policyinc: PolicyData[] = [];```

Comment: in a nutshell the error ```NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.``` indicates that somehow, the variable ```policyinc``` contains an object and not an array. If i were you i'd check that it is the case at all times.